# Change date format on editing

Tags: 8, datetime

I'm using a date field on my custom type, if I use "select" widget for node editing, I can choose only between "YMD","MDY" and "DMY" formats.

Is there a way to add custom formats? I need an "only year" format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, no.  The relevant code is in `\Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\DateTimeDatelistWidget::formElement()`.

What you want is usually called a "partial date", which is a bit of an oxymoron.  In Drupal, datetime fields are stored as `DrualDateTime` objects, which derive from `\DateTime` so have both a full date and a proper time and timezone associated with them.

A partial date (year, year+month), has to make assumptions about the rest of the parts.  For example, the date-only field [currently](https://www.drupal.org/node/2739290) sets the time to noon UTC.  A year only field would have to do something similar.

You may be able to create your own widget for the datetime field to do this.  You could take `DateTimeDatelistWidget` as a starting point, and trim it down to be just the year.  Then, you would need a masssageFormValues() to set the rest of the parts and then call the parent method (because `DateTimeWidgetBase::masssageFormValues()` does stuff, too).  This may or may not work, it is just the idea that popped into my head.

There is an open issue about this, https://www.drupal.org/node/2703037, that may or may not be implemeneted.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However, on D7 there is this option and Drupal completes the date, if I configure date widget in a "year only" format, even if it saves on db a complete datetime value. 
I'll try a new widget!

Comment: @arrubiu The datetime module in core plus related code scattered through core is not a straight port of the Drupal 7 Date module and friends.  It is a trimmed down version, and we are working to bring in some more features.  However, some some features from those modules are going to have to live in contrib.  A lot of the Drupal 7 Date modules had "do-it-all" plugins which are really hard to maintain long-term.  Since it is pretty easy to add widgets and formatters now, we are trying to abandon the "do-it-all" approach and just provide the building blocks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was thinking D7; I've removed my answer.

Comment: @MPD, it's ok, a usually develop custom modules on D7, I'm starting on D8 and so I've to study a lot ;) Thanks!